# Show score in twitter message

Tags: ios, xcode, twitter

I'm trying to integrate twitter sharing in my Sparrow framework. I got the twitter message to pop-up, but now I want to integrate the score of the game into it, something like:

I got X points scored with .....

The twitter message is activated with the following method:

```
-(void)onTwitterButtonClick:(SPEvent*)event{
{
    heightNum = [heightScoreText.text intValue];
    gemNum = [gemScoreText.text intValue];
    itemNum = [itemScoreText.text intValue];

    score = heightNum*10+gemNum*20+itemNum*100;

    SLComposeViewController *SControllers = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];


SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler myBlock = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
    [SControllers.view removeFromSuperview]; 
};   
SControllers.completionHandler =myBlock;

[SControllers setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"I collected %i points! Can you beat me? ", score]
];

[SControllers addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"]]; // set image in pic box

[Sparrow.currentController.view addSubview:SControllers.view];


 }
 }
```

heightNum, gemNum, itemNum and score are all integers.

heightScoreText, gemScoreText and itemScoreText are all SPTextfields and determined by:

```
   heightScoreText.text=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%i",heightNum*10];
   gemScoreText.text=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%i",gemNum*20];
   itemScoreText.text=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%i",itemNum*100];
```

If I activate the message now, I collected 0 points! :(

Can anyone help me? Be patient with me, I'm a total beginner at coding! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Did you double checked, and logged the value of score variable using NSLog. If it is not 0, then it should have your score in shared dialogue.